# Excel VBA to save folder location after selection through a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to give users the option to 'set' a default folder location, this would only be used to prefill further userform text boxes to save time having to go through the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`

I did use chdir, but that was written into the vba script, this location will differ from user to user and should only need to be set once upon addon installation

This is the code for the master folder selector:

```
Private Sub cmdfoldsel_Click()
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With fileExplorer
        If .Show = -1 Then 'Any folder is selected
            tbmasterloc.text = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Else ' else dialog is cancelled
            MsgBox "You have cancelled the dialogue"
            [folderPath] = "" ' when cancelled set blank as file path.
        End If
    End With
err:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

It is letting me choose the folder, but obviously the text disappears when I close ( I was using a close button with `unload me` but i thought that was deleting the text

An example of the second userform which will call that folder location is here:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    copyfromtb.Value = mfs.tbmasterloc.text
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub copyfromcmd_Click()

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        '.InitialFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    copyfromtb.Value = sItem

    Set fldr = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Couple of options **1.** Use a Public variable **2.** Use a hidden sheet **3.** Write to a temp txt file in the same folder **4.** Write to registry if user have enough rights

Comment: Thanks would the public variable allow the location to be 'saved' for the next time the userform is used?

Comment: Yes, provided the code did not break because of any error. However I would recommed using either point 2 or 3

Comment: would you have an exampe of using the temp text file? would it write the folder location, save and then if the userform location is changed it will overwrite with new location?

Comment: There are lot of example on how to read/write a text file from VBA. Do a quick google search. Remember, you can get the location from `Thisworkbook.Path` or even use user's temp directory.